# Sql update column with multiple same values

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried everything I could knew on this, basically I have a table of Clients ( Sql Server )

The table looks  like this

```
create table Client
(
Name nvarchar(100),(I want to be null)
EmployeesNo nvarchar(50),
CompanyCapital int
)
```

This simple table, the problem I encounter is when I want to update.
The problem is I can have multiple data with same values in Name so how to differentiate between the Values in Name to make them unique, Update looks like:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data"].ToString())
{
    if(con.State.ToString() == "Closed")
    {
    con.Open();
    }
    using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Update Client set Name = @name, EmployeesNo = @emp, CompanyCapital = @com where Name = @name2 (Should I update by some another thing that it will make it unique ???)",con))
    {
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name2",Mod));(Mod = string I initialized in constructor from another form;)
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name",textBox1.Text));
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emp",textBox2.Text));
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@com",textBox3.Text));
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

So when i update or user updates those values if i have multiple data with same values it will overwrite all of them and i don't want that, remember also that values are inserted and updated from textboxes.
I tried thinking of using Primary key but how do i know where to update at wich primary key, cause im using textboxes and i don't want the user to type in the ID of something, thanks.

Comment: Names are _never_, _ever_ unique. You _will_ have to use something else, and a unique ID is the most logical. You could use (as many systems do) a unique _username_ or even an e-mail address.

Comment: Use a primary key, normally an `int` column, for example `EmployeeId`.

Comment: Yes, thank you but how to update with where clause and update at this primary key, because i don't know the value of it

Comment: What's EmployeesNo? is this also duplicate?

Comment: Yes, please tell me is Multiple where Name = @name and EmployeesNo = emp and CapitalSocial = c .. is it good to have this multiple where conditions ?

Comment: If you do not have a unique key available, make sure you get it. Any possibly non-unique combination of fields is wrong, _wrong_, and again _wrong_. If EmployeeNo is unique, fine, use only that, but do NOT allow it to be updated then!

Answer (score 0):

You **should** use a primary key (like `ID`) if you need to **uniquely** identify your records.

In order to know the `ID` of the record that needs to be updated, just store the ID in your form as a hidden and readonly field.

Comment: Thank you, but with so many records somebody can enter let's say how to store them all? and where ?

Comment: @user3144640 I don't understand your question, could you please elaborate? I understand you have a database... that's what they are for, storing huge amount of data.

Comment: How to store the ID i mean when updating with where clause to put the ID to make them unique and Update the row i want not overwriting them all that's what i meant to say

Comment: @user3144640 Well, when you first construct the form, you should have an ID for the current record you are adding/modifying. If the record is a new one, you will have to generate a new (unique) ID, if you are updating an existing record you will have to load the ID from the DB along with the other data in your record.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `Parameters.Add` method, its SqlDbType. Not the Parameter Value.

instead  use `Parameters.AddWithValue`

or put value in object initializer,

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name2", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = Mod});
```

Comment: Thank you, Is better ? Someone told me Parameters.AddWithValue may cause Pollution

Comment: Not better, Not worse. Consider altogether. This is what you need now.

Comment: Good, but what do you use to Uniquely identify values and when updating not overwrite all same values?

Comment: Yes, please tell me is Multiple where Name = @name and EmployeesNo = emp and CapitalSocial = c .. is it good to have this multiple where conditions ?

Comment: you need change the deghin Table in DB. multiple condition its OK, but not recommended with many rows, or in possible case of two clients with all the details are the same.

Comment: Change the deghin ?or design ?